# Access Neo4J from another container

Tags: docker, go, neo4j, containers

I am running a neo4j graph database inside a docker container. I've written another service in Go that should be able to execute queries from its respective container. I cannot however get the connection between those two containers established.

the `dockerfile` of my database:

```
version: "3"
services:
  neo4j-db:
    image: neo4j:latest
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7473:7473"
      - "7687:7687"
    expose:
      - 7474
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.18.10
    volumes:
      - //C/Users/<user>/Desktop/neoj4/4.0/config:/conf
networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.18.0/24
```

My `neo4j.conf`:

```
dbms.connector.https.advertised_address=localhost:7473

dbms.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

dbms.connector.http.advertised_address=localhost:7474

dbms.memory.pagecache.size=512M

dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address=127.18.18.10:7687

dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=100M size
dbms.directories.logs=/logs
```

And finally inside my Go container:

```
 uri := "bolt://127.18.18.10:7687"
    username := "neo4j"
    password := "test" 
    var (
        err      error
        driver   neo4j.Driver
        session  neo4j.Session
        result   neo4j.Result
        greeting interface{}
    )
    fmt.Println("Connecting to Neo4j")
    driver, err = neo4j.NewDriver(uri, neo4j.BasicAuth(username, password, ""), useConsoleLogger(neo4j.ERROR))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR:" , err)
    }
    defer driver.Close()

    fmt.Println("Getting Session")

    session, err = driver.Session(neo4j.AccessModeWrite)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR:" , err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
```

When calling the function the execution gets stuck after `fmt.Println("Getting Session")` without throwing any errors for 30 seconds and then simply terminates.

I also made sure to have both containers on the same network (`app_net`). I can ping between the containers without issue. However, trying telnet from the go-container to neo4j yields `Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Browser access on neo4j works and from what I see the containers are on the same network.

Any advice or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

After spending some additional time, I've managed to get it working. I took the following steps:

1. Use the container's hostname as `uri` (i.e. `"bolt://container_name"`).
2. Remove encryption to prevent a TLS error:

```
  if driver, err = neo4j.NewDriver(uri, neo4j.BasicAuth(username, password, ""), func(config *neo4j.Config) {
    config.Log = neo4j.ConsoleLogger(neo4j.ERROR)
    config.Encrypted = false
  }); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  defer driver.Close()
```